# Finding the type of an object using PHP-Parser

Tags: php, oop, parsing, php-parser

Using [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser), when I am traversing the nodes in a program, how do I find the type of an object?  For example, in the program below, when I encounter the node `$a->some_method();` how do I find that $a's type is 'TestClass' ?

```
$a = new TestClass();

$a->some_method();
```

Now, I know that I can keep track internally that the object $a is of the type TestClass and that works fine for programs in a single file, but I'm not sure how to keep track of the type of an object in programs that span multiple files and I'm particularly confused about how to maintain the type of a variable when it is returned from a function or method.  Am I going about it all wrong?  Is there a simpler way using PHP-Parser to find out the type of an object?

Comment: A parser really just turns the source code into an AST. It does not evaluate types at all, that'd be the next step in the chain and the job of the compiler. You'll have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

It's not possible to do it without actually executing the code.